# The restriction of f to U is injective or surjective or both...?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disc in the complex plane and $U=D\setminus \{-1/2 ,1/2\}$.

Also let 
$$H_{1}=\{f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\mid \text{$f$ is holomorphic and bounded} \}$$
$$H_{2}=\{f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\mid \text{$f$ is holomorphic and bounded} \}$$

Then the map $r:H_{1} \rightarrow H_{2}$ given by $r(f)=f|_{U}$, the restriction of $f $ to $U$, is injective or bijective or both...

My Efforts: I tried to solve this , using the concept of restriction map but didn't get any hint.Please give some idea...

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` for braces, and `\text{ some text }` for text inside math.

Answer (score 0):

If $r(f)=r(g)$ then  $f(z)=g(z)$ except when $z \in \{-\frac 1 2 , \frac 1  2\}$. But then continuity implies $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$ so $r$ is injective. It is  surjective because any bounded holomorphic function on $U$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $D$ since it has removable singularities at $\pm \frac 1 2$.